# Time and Space Complexity of this Palindrome Algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, palindrome, space-complexity

Can someone tell me the time and space complexity for this algorithm? Basically the function takes in a string and the function must return true if it's a palindrome (same backwards as it is forwards) or false if it is not.

I am thinking it is **O(n)** for both but please correct me if I am wrong.

```js
function isPalindrome(string) {
    var reversing = string.split("").reverse().join("")
    return string === reversing
}
```

Comment: Yes it is O(n) for both.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure the *O(n)* complexity is anyhow visible here, because you're not actually implementing the *Algorithm*. You rather use the String API, the code of which, you also don't present here. So, speaking from this code only, it's *constant*.. but as internal calls are doing the job which is O(n), it's not constant.. but this is not obvious from this question. Generally, try to implement algorithm yourself when you're curious about the time-space complexity (or see the implementation).

Comment: I meant behind the scenes though using the built in split, reverse and join methods.

Comment: Then it's better to provide the code which you are examining. Not everyone will open their IDE, download the sources and see the implementation under the hood. Anyways, my suggestion is still valid - do not *implement* algorithms like this.. as you don't actually implement any algorithm here.

Comment: Also, please always add the corresponding tag of the language you're using.

Comment: @SamuelP: you can accept the answer by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 2):

Your function has a time and space complexity of **O(string.length)** because it constructs an array of characters and then a new string with the characters in reverse order, with the same length as the original string. Comparing these strings has the same time complexity.

Note however that this works for single words but not for complete phrases: a phrase that can be read in both directions with the same letters, but not necessarily the same spacing is also a palindrome.

Here is an alternative version:

```js
function isPalindrome(string) {
    string = string.replace(/ /g, "");
    var reverse = string.split("").reverse().join("");
    return string === reverse;
}
```

This function has the same time and space complexity of **O(string.length)**.